# How to right align the output according to the length of the largest word in a list in python 3.xx

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops, string-formatting, python-3.6

I have:

```
a = ['bicycle','airplane','car','boat']

for i in a:
    print("{:>??}".format(i)) # ?? because I dont know what to do here
```

My desired output:

```
  bicycle
 airplane
      car
     boat
```

I need to align my output such that all the words are aligned right with the spacing as big as the longest word?? (I have a question mark because I think this is the only way I am going to achieve my desired output). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Pre-compute the length of the largest string and pass it as a separate parameter to `format`.

```
l = len(max(a, key=len))

for i in a:
    print("{n:>{w}}".format(n=i, w=l))

 bicycle
airplane
     car
    boat
```

---

**Option 2**
An alternative using `str.rjust`:

```
for i in a:
    print(i.rjust(l))  # same `l` as computed in Option 1


 bicycle
airplane
     car
    boat
```

---

**Option 3**
You can also print a dump of `pd.Series.to_string`:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.Series(a).to_string())

0     bicycle
1    airplane
2         car
3        boat
```

---

Other tabulation packages (I use `tabulate`) can also be used to good effect here.